# Issues with .selectedIndex incorrectly filling form

Tags: javascript, arrays

I created a quiz as a form, results come after the form has been clicked. Each result comes out as a value. I need the result to populate in a form generated by Marketo (knowledge of marketo not needed right now). So the values need to show up after a click, which is fine, I have the values showing up, but it's the incorrect value.

Can't call to the correct index that corresponds with the value for some reason. Any help?

Form code:

```
<select id="personaBucket" name="personaBucket" class="mktoField mktoHasWidth mktoRequired" style="width: 300px;">
<option value="">I need to work on...</option>
<option value="Customer">Customer</option>
<option value="Compliance">Compliance</option>
<option value="Continuity">Continuity</option>
</select>
```

JS (to assign value for quiz result):

```
if (customer < continuity && customer < compliance) {
        result = customer;
       } else if (compliance < continuity && compliance < customer) {
        result = compliance;
       } else if (continuity < compliance && continuity < customer) {
        result = continuity;
       } else {
        result = continuity;
       }

    grading = [
       {score:customer,value:"customer",feedback:"You need to work on customer experience. Fill out the form below to learn more."},
       {score:compliance,value:"compliance",feedback:"You need to work on compliance. Fill out the form below to learn more."},
       {score:continuity,value:"continuity",feedback:"You need to work on continuity. Fill out the form below to learn more."}
       ];
```

JS (to have value correspond to quiz result):

```
var select = document.getElementById("personaBucket");
    var persona = "Persona is: ";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
        persona=persona + "\n" + select.options[i].text + " has index: " + select.options[i].index;
    }
    console.log(persona);

    for (i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
    var selectNone = function () {
        document.getElementById("personaBucket").selectedIndex = "0"; 
    };
    var selectCustomer = function () {
        document.getElementById("personaBucket").selectedIndex = "1"; 
    };
    var selectCompliance = function () {
        document.getElementById("personaBucket").selectedIndex = "2"; 
    };
    var selectContinuity = function () {
        document.getElementById("personaBucket").selectedIndex = "3";
    };
    }

    for(i=0; i<grading.length; i++) {
    if(result == grading[i].score) {
    if (grading[i].value = customer) { 
        selectCustomer ();
        }
    else if (grading[i].value = compliance) { 
        selectCompliance ();
    }
    else if (grading[i].value = continuity) { 
        selectContinuity ();
    }
    else { 
        selectContinuity ();
    }
}
}
```

The index is coming out wrong even though I'm calling to correct index #

**EDIT:** Got rid of selectIndex, but the biggest issue was that I didn't put "" around my values below and, like Rob mentioned below, replacing the = with ==. So, I replaced this:

```
for(i=0; i<grading.length; i++) {
    if(result == grading[i].score) {
    if (grading[i].value = customer) { 
        selectCustomer ();
        }
    else if (grading[i].value = compliance) { 
        selectCompliance ();
    }
    else if (grading[i].value = continuity) { 
        selectContinuity ();
    }
    else { 
        selectContinuity ();
    }
}
}
```

With this:

```
for(i=0; i<grading.length; i++) {
        if(result == grading[i].score) {
            personaVal = grading[i].value;
        }
    }

    if ( personaVal == "customer" ) {
    $('#personaBucket').children().remove().end().append('<option selected value="customer">Customer</option>') ;
    }
    if ( personaVal == "compliance" ) {
    $('#personaBucket').children().remove().end().append('<option selected value="compliance">Compliance</option>') ;
    }
    if ( personaVal == "continuity" ) {
    $('#personaBucket').children().remove().end().append('<option selected value="continuity">Continuity</option>') ;
    }
```

Works perfectly now, thanks for the help!

Comment: Using a linter like ESLint will help you discover small errors immediately.

Comment: Also, you're assigning to variables inside a `for` loop. The value is going to be that of the last iteration. The functions are identical anyway, so the `for` loop has no purpose there.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier just to set `value` of the `<select>` than to mess with `selectedIndex`:

```
select.value = 'Customer';
```

While we're at it, all of your functions do pretty much the same exact thing - it would be better to have this be one function that accepts an index and returns another function that contains the index in a closure:

```
function setSelectValue(val) {
   return function() {
      select.value = val;
   }
}
var selectContinuity = setSelectValue('Customer');
var selectCustomer = setSelectValue('Continuity');
```

One more thing, assignment is not the same as comparison:

```
if (grading[i].value = customer) {
```

Unless `customer` is falsey, this will always return true since assignment statements return the value that is being set. You should at the very least use `==` for comparisons, but it is much better to use `===` to check value and type of the value for equality.

Comment: Hmm ok, I can give it a try. I set my values as lower cases, as seen in the grading json code above, so when I did (grading[i]value = customer), that was because I was validating that it the value was customer and not continuity or compliance. I can't set the value because the quiz sets the value, so I'm not sure how to tell the code that IF the winner is compliance, then compliance should be the value of the <option> in the <select> without using selecindex, because calling to the value of the options has not worked.

Comment: Got rid of the selectIndex and I used the ==, but I did need to "" around the values in the if () sections, which is why when I == nothing was happening. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: No problem, glad to help out :-)

Answer (score 0):

Got rid of selectIndex, but the biggest issue was that I didn't put "" around my values below and, like Rob mentioned, replacing the = with ==. So, I replaced this:

```
for(i=0; i<grading.length; i++) {
    if(result == grading[i].score) {
    if (grading[i].value = customer) { 
        selectCustomer ();
        }
    else if (grading[i].value = compliance) { 
        selectCompliance ();
    }
    else if (grading[i].value = continuity) { 
        selectContinuity ();
    }
    else { 
        selectContinuity ();
    }
}
}
```

With this:

```
for(i=0; i<grading.length; i++) {
        if(result == grading[i].score) {
            personaVal = grading[i].value;
        }
    }

    if ( personaVal == "customer" ) {
    $('#personaBucket').children().remove().end().append('<option selected value="customer">Customer</option>') ;
    }
    if ( personaVal == "compliance" ) {
    $('#personaBucket').children().remove().end().append('<option selected value="compliance">Compliance</option>') ;
    }
    if ( personaVal == "continuity" ) {
    $('#personaBucket').children().remove().end().append('<option selected value="continuity">Continuity</option>') ;
    }
```

Thanks for all the help!